# Multiple developers on one project

Tags: development

we are working on an SP project with multiple developers.  We all have our own SP dev machine to work from.  We then have a central "production" box which we will eventually deploy our code to.

My question is, I can see that we can each work from our own code locally without interrupting other developers.  However, what happens if I want to create a new List.  If I do that locally, nobody else can use it as it won't be checked in to source control - it's just in my local DB.  Does that mean all other devs have to then create the same list (by hand), including all item definitions, making sure all column names are spelled exactly the same etc?  It seems like there must be a better way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Create [List definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023.aspx) in the visual studio and deploy with the solution. But if you'd like to use the same data you will have to export it as a template with saved data and then import it on the another machine